# Something special about 2022-02-02

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I was looking at the date today and it made me think of a mathematical object.

Like March 14, which is known by some as as "Pi day".

So the date is 2022-02-02.  What mathematical object can it be linked to?

Comment: Must it be unique like 3/14, or can other similar dates this year hold the same property?

Comment: Other dates have the same property.  Not difficult to guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2022-02-02 can be linked to

> **the [Cantor ternary set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_ternary_set) on the interval** $[0,1]$. Informally, this mathematical object is created by repeatedly removing the middle third from each line segment, as seen below.
>
>  [image: Cantor ternary set]
>
>  <sup>*Credit: 127 "rect" from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cantor_set_in_seven_iterations.svg)*</sup>
>
>  It is famous for having certain mathematical properties, such as being a perfect set that is nowhere dense.

This is because

> the Cantor set above contains those ternary decimals that can be written without a $1$, and we can associate the date with $0.20220202_3$.

Comment: Yep!  That is what today's date made me think of.